# Change exit value on getLine exception in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a student project in Haskell and i'm having a problem with getLine's behaviour.
Here's the code (simplified) :

```
main :: IO()
main = do
str <- getLine
putStrLn str
```

What i'd like to do is, when the user presses Ctrl+D, be able to exitWith (ExitFailure 84).
getLine simply prints an error and exit the program (and returns 1)

```
deBruijn: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
```

How to change this behaviour ? I only want to change the exit value to 84.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Handling_errors_in_Haskell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program never sees Control-D. What it *does* see is the fact that standard input has been closed, in this case by your *terminal* in response to Control-D being typed. This means you want to catch the EOF condition before `getLine` tries to read a line from a closed file.

```
import System.IO
import System.Exit

main :: IO ()
main = do
    isClosed <- isEOF
    if isClosed 
      then exitWith (ExitFailure 84)
      else getLine >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: A minor correction: `import System.IO` is needed for `isEOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually checking for `isEof` you could just catch the IO exception as it happens:

```
import Control.Exception (catch)
import System.IO.Error(isEOFError)
import System.Exit

tryMain :: IO ()
tryMain = getLine >>= putStrLn

main :: IO ()
main = tryMain `catch` (\e ->
  if isEOFError e
  then exitWith (ExitFailure 84)
  else exitWith (ExitFailure 99))
```

As you can in general not rule out IO exceptions in advance, this is the approach I'd recommend.